# ActiveRecord has many through with both being polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the association setup like the below, but I'm getting errors/exceptions thrown from Rails telling me that I don't have the associations set up properly.

Here's what I have:

```
class Case
  has_many :case_accesses, as: :policy, inverse_of: :case, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :agents, through: :case_accesses, source: :ownable, source_type: 'Agent'
end

class CaseAccess
  belongs_to :policy, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
end

class Agent
  has_many :case_accesses, as: :ownable, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :cases, through: :case_accesses
end
```

The error from Rails:

Could not find the source association(s) "case" or :cases in model CaseAccess. Try 'has_many :cases, :through => :case_accesses, :source => '. Is it one of policy, connection, or ownable?

I tried setting the source to ownable and it's causing problems in my query.  How should I be setting up this association?  It's a traditional has many through, except on one side the `policy` can be either of type `Case` or `Ppae`, and the `ownable` can be of type `Agent` or `User`.

Columns for tables:

```
Case
-id

CaseAccess
-id
-policy_id
-policy_type
-ownable_id
-ownable_type

Agent
-id
```

Comment: Could you please also post the columns for each of these tables - just for additional reference

Answer (score 1):

A Case has many case_accesses as policy. Is the CaseAccess the policy, or is the Case the policy for the CaseAccess?

I believe you need to change

`has_many :case_accesses, as: :policy, inverse_of: :case, dependent: :destroy`

to

`has_many :case_accesses, inverse_of: :policy, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: Ehh no that didn't do it.

Comment: I got it, posting answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what did it:

```
class Case
  has_many :case_accesses, as: :policy, inverse_of: :policy, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :agents, through: :case_accesses, source: :ownable, source_type: 'Agent'

  has_many :users, through: :case_accesses, source: :ownable, source_type: 'User'
end

class CaseAccess
  belongs_to :policy, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
end

class Agent
  has_many :case_accesses, as: :ownable, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :cases, through: :case_accesses, source: :policy, source_type: 'Case'
end
```